# APT can't fetch Firefox archives

Tags: apt, updates, firefox

I'm trying to install Firefox on Ubuntu 20.04 (running under WSL2). When I try `sudo apt install firefox` I get error:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 firefox amd64   85.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_85.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
```

I've been able to install other packages, so I don't think the repository is misconfigured.

What to do?

Answer (score 3):

85.0 has been superseded and removed from the repositories. That's why it's 404 Not Found.

Run `sudo apt update` to refresh apt's database of available packages and versions, then try installing again.

Comment: Doh!  I should have thought of that.  Thanks for the help.